# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets with 2 rules

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I want column A  to highlight a specific colour only if C has a value of 0. I have tried but even if the cells are blank it still highlights them.
It is for quantity reasons to make column a1 stand out.

Answer (score 1):

try this custom formula:

```
=AND(C1=0,  C1<>"")
```

[image: 0]